# Is there a way to make cmake find_package config mode VERSION selection automatically work with complex paths or is my path structure flawed?

Tags: cmake

I want to have find_package in config mode is the user points cmake with the SDK `<Project>`_ROOT variable then possibly calls find_package passing in version numbers and [setting the flags for version number sorting](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_SORT_ORDER.html#variable:CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_SORT_ORDER).

```
set(CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_SORT_ORDER NATURAL)
find_package(<Project> CONFIG)
```

CMake would then automatically finds the latest config.cmake file and everyone is happy.

The problem I have is the SDK folder structure:

```
<Project>/<Version>/<Toolset>/cmake/config.cmake
SDK/2.1.1/v140/cmake/SDKconfig.cmake
```

Where `<Project>` is the root folder.  Based on the [kinds of paths searched](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure) I could make it work if I reduced the path by 1 folder combining the names and added the project name as a prefix for the subdir but that feels very weird.

Other ideas I am considering is creating a dummy config as a find_package forwarder or maybe an importer in the middle of the path that re-tries a find package or imports things further down to the correct version or maybe toolset but haven't pursued that yet.  It might again require that the version number or other have the project name as a prefix.

Is placing these highly specific content config files that far down the wrong approach?

Comment: Why not add `/path/to/SDK/2.1.1/v140` to the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`?

Comment: Well the idea was that subsequent updates would just be found automatically or the user could specify a version number argument with the find_package command.  

Otherwise yes users could just point directly at the config they intend to use and manage the pathing internally on their cmake with things like
${SDK_ROOT}/${SDK_Version}/${SDK_Toolset}

It just felt odd to me that we have the power to specify versions with find package but maybe that's more appropriately used with installed packages/modules or simpler setups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [`find_package` search procedure](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure) you'll see that it will consider directories *prefixed* with the project name. Here are the Windows-compatible structures CMake will consider:

```
   <prefix>/                                                       (W)
   <prefix>/(cmake|CMake)/                                         (W)
   <prefix>/<name>*/                                               (W)
   <prefix>/<name>*/(cmake|CMake)/                                 (W)
** <prefix>/<name>*/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/cmake/<name>*/         (W/U)
   <prefix>/<name>*/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/<name>*/               (W/U)
   <prefix>/<name>*/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/<name>*/(cmake|CMake)/ (W/U)
```

The fifth one down, the one I marked with `**`, is the most promising. Note that `lib/<arch>` is only searched if `CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE` is set and `*` means "0 or more characters"; however, the `*` in `lib*` can only be `64`, `32`, or `x32` (and only on Unix).

---

So here's one *suggestion* that's mostly useful if you're going to create an eventual directory structure that contains multiple project versions and multiple toolset versions:

```
<prefix>/<Project>-<Version>/lib/<Toolset>/cmake/<Project>/<Project>Config.cmake
```

Your users should then set `CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE` to `v141` or whichever (I have found it is blank by default on Windows). As long as you have a `<Project>ConfigVersion.cmake` file, users setting the version via `find_package` should get the correct one.

I tested this locally while writing the answer, but I've never deployed this myself. So I can't really tell you how great an idea this is beyond that it seems like it would technically work.